# Как узнать есть ли в определенном радиусе другой объект?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Идея такова, что враги движутся влево, вправо и должны остановиться если впереди в определенном радиусе присутствует другой объект. Если проще говоря они должны строиться в шеренгу, как солдаты. И вот вопрос, как узнать есть ли в определенном радиусе другой объект?

Comment: Самое простое уже пробовали, попарно проверять расстояния между объектами?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно пускать [Raycast](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html) в нужном направлении, чтобы узнать, есть ли что-то на этой линии или нет. Это будет работать только для физических объектов, а большое количество таких операций будет трудозатратным.

Если нужно определять расстояние только среди солдат, то нужно иметь некий класс, который имеет в себе список всех солдат и уже из него получать эвенты, что солдаты сблизились.

Само расстояние между объектами можно получить через их позиции:

```
Vector3 a = Vector3.back;
Vector3 b = Vector3.down;
var distance = Vector3.Distance(a, b);
```